# Use iterrows in pandas to find mismatches between strings, bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have the following pandas Dataframe in Python3.5:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe(...)
print(df)
```

which outputs

```
string1        string2
'abcdefg...'   'abcSefg...'
'Iknowhow...'  'Eknowhow...'
'Thecatis...'  'Thekatis...'
...
```

I first wanted to find the location of mismatches between `string1` and `string2` and append this to the Dataframe `df`. I use this code:

```
df["different_positions"] = [[i for i in range(len(row.string2)) 
    if row.string1[i] != row.string2[i]] for _, row in df.iterrows()]
```

That will give me all the positions were mismatches occur. Now, I would like a separate column which outputs each letter of the mismatch. For example, in `string2`, there is an `S` instead of a `d` in the first row, an `E` instead of `I` in the second row, etc.

I thought the code would be

```
df["different_letters"] = [[i for i in row.string2
    if row.string1[i] != row.string2[i]] for _, row in df.iterrows()]
```

However, it appears this isn't correct. I get a `NameError` at `for _, row`, i.e.

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

How do I output the mismatched letter to correspond to the mismatched position?

Comment: What is the output you're getting?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan For the 'different_positions' column, I get a list of all mismatched positions, e.g. `[5, 11, 28, 81]`. For the error, see edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String iteration returns characters, not indices. In other words, `i for i in row.string2` will go through the *characters* of `row.string2`, not the corresponding indices.

So

```
df["different_letters"] = [[i for i in row.string2
if row.string1[i] != row.string2[i]] for _, row in df.iterrows()]
```

is incorrect because you're effectively asking what `row.string1['a']` is if `row.string1` contains an `a`. String indices *must* be integers.

Instead, you want to do

```
df["different_letters"] = [[j for i, j in enumerate(row.string2)
if row.string1[i] != row.string2[i]] for _, row in df.iterrows()]
```

`enumerate` lets you iterate through both the index *and* the corresponding element in an iterable. Here, `j` is the corresponding character, `i` is its index, and you can now compare by index but only return the corresponding character.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. By the way, could you explain to me the syntax `for _, row in ...`? I use it, but I'm not entirely sure why we type `_`. Does this stand for `rowindex`?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang No, the `_` is just an arbitrary random character. You could change it to 'foo' or 'bar' with no difficulties. The convention is to use `_` for variables whose values we don't need but have to take anyway. `df.iterrows()' returns `rowindex` and `row` - since we don't need `rowindex`, we just denote it by `_` and move on.